# How to set Radio Group View to not clickable

Tags: android, radio-group, android-radiogroup

I want to set my RadioGroupView to not clickable so that the user can't click on the buttons. I tried `mRadioGroup.isActivated = false` but it has no effect on my RadioGroup View. Have somebody a hint for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable for each button

```
for (int i = 0; i < mRadioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
    mRadioGroup.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to disable the radio buttons inside radio group you need to manually disable each button with the help of `radioButton1.setEnabled(false)` method.
However better way is to loop through the radio buttons inside mRadioGroup with the help of `getChildAt()` method

```
for (int i = 0; i < mRadioGroup.getChildCount(); i++){
 mRadioGroup.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried set `RadioGroupView clickable = false?` 
If it's not working, you can put a View overlay whole RadioGroup layout and set this view clickable = true.

Answer (score 2):

Building on [Prithvi Bhola's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52474647/2143225) you can use a Kotlin extension function that you simply add to your `Activity`:

```
fun RadioGroup.setChildrenEnabled(enabled: Boolean) {
    for (i in 0 until childCount) {
       getChildAt(i).isEnabled = enabled
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you need to you can simply disable or enable all `RadioButtons` in the `RadioGroup`:

```
mRadioGroup.setChildrenEnabled(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

RadioGroup cannot be disabled directly, we have to loop through the radio button and set it enabled as false.

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rg.getChildCount(); i++){
    ((RadioButton)rg.getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(false);
}
```

Hope this will help.